# Return JSONArray from a Service Api Rest in Angular

Tags: angular

I am fairly new to Angular and Api Rest. I want call a URL from the service and respond with a JSONArray. For example: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

I'm calling a service from App.component and return a JSONArray but it show only from console.

**My App.component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataApiService } from 'src/app/services/data-api.service';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
   constructor(private rest: DataApiService) { }

   ngOnInit() {
      this.getListProducts();
   }

   getListProducts(){
      this.rest.getAllProducts().subscribe(data => {
         console.log(data);
      });
   }
}
```

**My Service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})

export class DataApiService {
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

   getAllProducts(){
      const localUrl = 'assets/data/smartphone.json';
      return this.http.get(localUrl);
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to change the code `console.log(data);` to anything you want from App.component

Comment: What do you mean by *return a JSONArray but it show only from console*?

Comment: I want call function from an app android, but i don't know how return data. i use "Postman" for test my GET request, but it return "HTML" of view component in the body.

Comment: I don’t see any observable on your service. But however you have imported it. Try adding observable with some interface. So it gets binded automatically

Answer (score 0):

Here how you access data

Declare variable

```
myData:any;
```

then catch that data

```
catchAndPrint(data)
{
this.myData:any=data;
console.log("Return data :",this.myData);
}
```

in your function

```
ngOnInit() {
      this.getListProducts();
   }

   getListProducts(){
      this.rest.getAllProducts().subscribe(data => {
         this.catchAndPrint(data);
      });
   }
```